# Является ли допустимым конструкция delete this?

Tags: c++

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке. Более подробно, рассмотрим, к примеру, такой код:

```
class A
{
public:
A () = default;
~A () = default;
void destroy_me ()
{
  delete this;
}
};

int main ()
{
  A *a = new A ();
  a->destroy_me ();
  return 0;
}
```

Корректен ли код выше ? Считается ли это стандартом C++ как UB ? Просьба с цитатами или пунктами стандарта, сам пока не смог разобраться.

Comment: Как говорит [FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-this), ответ — нет, но вы обязаны быть уверены в том что объект был выделен именно через `new`.

Comment: То есть "да, корректен, нет, ub нет".

Answer (score -1):

Нужно cначала понимать как работает `delete`. Он вызывает деструктор объекта,
потом вызывает системную функцию, отвечающую за освобождение памяти.
Нельзя гарантировать, что объект был выделен на системной куче,
ибо он может быть выделен кастомным аллокатором, или даже на стеке.
Во всех этих 2-ух случаях будет UB.

Comment: *"Нельзя гарантировать"* Ну, почему нельзя. Программист в своем коде может гарантировать.